# XCode 8 misplacement of views

Tags: ios, view, xcode8

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here....Super basic stuff but I see no other complaints on the net so maybe it is something I am doing wrong??

I'm using XCode 8 and I find that when aligning a view to the center X of a peer view that is itself centered on the screen, XCode is in fact setting the alignment to the center X of the top-level view. Screen shots:
[image: Super basic UIView and UILabel]

This is a super basic UIView with a UILabel aligned to the UIView center X (constraint is highlighted).
Below is the view hierachy... no surprises...

[image: View hierarchy]

And the highlighted constraint:

[image]

You can see that the constraint relates the MyLabel.centerX to MyView.centerX as is expected. The relationship is 0.5 which means that MyLabel should be positioned 25% of the way from the left edge of MyView. It is not - if you look carefully at the first screenshot you can see that it is not 25% from the edge of MyView but 25% from the edge of the screen. Changing the Storyboard to an iPad screen as below shows the problem more clearly:

[image: iPad screen]

This only seems to happen if the view that you are aligning to is itself centered on the top-level view. As below, if I create another view that is not centered on the top-level view, all is fine.

[image: iPhone SE - non-centered view]

And iPad rendition:

[image: iPad view]

Any thoughts would be appreciated....

Comment: I have backup, So, I just open my backup in Xcode 7.3 open Storyboard as Source code copy and paste it in my latest code. That's It. It work for me.

Answer (score 1):

> You can see that the constraint relates the MyLabel.centerX to MyView.centerX as is expected. The relationship is 0.5 which means that MyLabel should be positioned 25% of the way from the left edge of MyView.

By putting MyLabel's centerX to MyView's centerX you're not actually aligning  MyLabel's centerX to MyView's leading edge...

Since MyView's centerX is aligned to the root UIView's centerX, MyLabel's centerX is doing exactly what you assigned it to do.

Transitive property: if a = b, and b = c then a = c. In this case the centerX of the root UIView (superview)

You should change the second item from `MyView.Center X` to My View's leading edge

Answer (score 0):

I think you may just have a misconception about what a multiplier means when applied to a center constraint. A thing is centered in relation to its superview. The easiest way to see this is with a configuration like this:

[image]

The orange view knows nothing about centers; it is positioned horizontally by the leading edge constraint that I've highlighted. The blue view has its center x aligned with the orange view's center x, *with a multiplier of 2*. As you can see, the result has nothing to do with the orange view's width: it means "twice as far to the right as the center of the orange view is".